Hydrogen radial equation solution's boundary condition for $r \to 0$
I am studying the hydrogen atom and I am analysing the radial equation: $$\left[\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{\hbar^2l(l+1)}{2m}+ V(r)\right]u=Eu$$ with $V(r)$ equal to the Coloumb potential. My professor stated that the divergence of the effective potential for $r \to 0$ requires that the condition $$u(0)=0$$ must be imposed. I do not understand where this boundary condition comes from.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90987/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134719/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183045/2451 and links therein.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/118886/probability-density-at-the-nucleus

Why isn't there a $1/r^2$ in the term for the angular momentum?

@JosBergervoet I forgot to write it. Thanks a lot for the correction.

OK. And this solution $u(r) $ is presumably $r\psi(r) $, the usual substitution. So $u(0)$ must be zero just to keep the actual wave function finite. $$$$
